# Use R to generate sales report from XML data? Convert to Dataframe?

Tags: r, xml, xpath

I have some online order data as XML. I want to make a report with the total number of orders, sales, returns, etc.

```
<ArrayOfItem>
<Item>
<total>333.3</total>
<terminalid>1</terminalid>
<subtotal>330</subtotal>
<storeid>1000</storeid>
<itemlist>
<TransactionLine><LineNumber>1</LineNumber><Name>Moto G Turbo Edition Black</Name><ItemUPC>5479892348535</ItemUPC><Quantity>1</Quantity><SalePrice>330</SalePrice><IndividualPrice>330</IndividualPrice><CreatedDate>2017-06-13T09:42:52.1411148Z</CreatedDate><Status>0</Status><ShippingCost>0</ShippingCost><TotalTax>3.3</TotalTax><AppliedTaxes><LineTax><TaxId>0</TaxId><Amount>0</Amount><CreatedDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CreatedDate></LineTax></AppliedTaxes><AppliedDiscounts /><ItemCondition>SellableAsNew</ItemCondition><ReturnReason>PoorQuality</ReturnReason></TransactionLine>
</itemlist>
<transactiontenders>1</transactiontenders>
<transactiontenders>2</transactiontenders>
<transactiontenders>4</transactiontenders>
<transactiontype>1</transactiontype>
<transdate>2017-06-13T09:52:54Z</transdate>
<transtime>09:52</transtime>
</Item>
<Item>
<total>343.59</total>
<terminalid>1</terminalid>
<subtotal>340.29</subtotal>
<storeid>1000</storeid>
<itemlist>
<TransactionLine><LineNumber>1</LineNumber><Name>Moto G Turbo Edition Black</Name><ItemUPC>5479892348535</ItemUPC><Quantity>1</Quantity><SalePrice>330</SalePrice><IndividualPrice>330</IndividualPrice><CreatedDate>2017-06-13T09:53:00.8548823Z</CreatedDate><Status>0</Status><ShippingCost>0</ShippingCost><TotalTax>3.3</TotalTax><AppliedTaxes><LineTax><TaxId>0</TaxId><Amount>0</Amount><CreatedDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CreatedDate></LineTax></AppliedTaxes><AppliedDiscounts /><ItemCondition>SellableAsNew</ItemCondition><ReturnReason>PoorQuality</ReturnReason></TransactionLine>
<TransactionLine><LineNumber>2</LineNumber><Name>This Was A Man</Name><ItemUPC>777221028297</ItemUPC><Quantity>1</Quantity><SalePrice>4.99</SalePrice><IndividualPrice>4.99</IndividualPrice><CreatedDate>2017-06-13T09:53:07.8263895Z</CreatedDate><Status>0</Status><ShippingCost>0</ShippingCost><TotalTax>0</TotalTax><AppliedTaxes /><AppliedDiscounts /><ItemCondition>SellableAsNew</ItemCondition><ReturnReason>PoorQuality</ReturnReason></TransactionLine>
<TransactionLine><LineNumber>3</LineNumber><Name>A Prisoner of Birth</Name><ItemUPC>4000111222302</ItemUPC><Quantity>1</Quantity><SalePrice>5.3</SalePrice><IndividualPrice>5.3</IndividualPrice><CreatedDate>2017-06-13T09:53:11.124866Z</CreatedDate><Status>0</Status><ShippingCost>0</ShippingCost><TotalTax>0</TotalTax><AppliedTaxes /><AppliedDiscounts /><ItemCondition>SellableAsNew</ItemCondition><ReturnReason>PoorQuality</ReturnReason></TransactionLine>
</itemlist>
<transactiontenders>1</transactiontenders><transactiontenders>2</transactiontenders>
<transactiontype>1</transactiontype>
<transdate>2017-06-13T09:53:29Z</transdate>
<transtime>09:53</transtime>
</Item>
</ArrayOfItem>
```

I have done something like this:

```
library(XML)
y <- xmlToDataFrame('C:\\App\\06122017.XML')
nrow(y) # To get total number of order
doc = xmlInternalTreeParse('C:\\App\\06122017.XML')
transactionlineItems <- xpathSApply(doc, '//TransactionLine') # list
transactionlineItems
```

I tried this to get the sum of totals, but it doesn't work.

```
colSums(y[,c("total")]) # not working
```

`transactionlineItems` is a list of XML elements, from which i want to derive a dataframe, apply some logic (to see if the particular line item is a sale or a return), and create separate totals for the sales and returns. Also, get the count of each product to see which product has sold more. Right now I'm am doing this browser side, by applying the logic to the same data in JSON format. I want to move it to server side and have chosen R programming.

Answer (score 0):

**If you really have your heat set on dataframe conversion:**

You were on the right track.  This answer combines your `xmlToDataFrame` and `xpathSApply` ideas. You should be careful to make sure that numeric values aren't handled as characters, or even factors.

```
library(XML)

order.xml.string <- '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ArrayOfItem>
<Item>
<total>333.3</total>
<terminalid>1</terminalid>
<subtotal>330</subtotal>
<storeid>1000</storeid>
<itemlist>
<TransactionLine>
<LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
<Name>Moto G Turbo Edition Black</Name>
<ItemUPC>5479892348535</ItemUPC>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
<SalePrice>330</SalePrice>
<IndividualPrice>330</IndividualPrice>
<CreatedDate>2017-06-13T09:42:52.1411148Z</CreatedDate>
<Status>0</Status>
<ShippingCost>0</ShippingCost>
<TotalTax>3.3</TotalTax>
<AppliedTaxes>
<LineTax>
<TaxId>0</TaxId>
<Amount>0</Amount>
<CreatedDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CreatedDate>
</LineTax>
</AppliedTaxes>
<AppliedDiscounts/>
<ItemCondition>SellableAsNew</ItemCondition>
<ReturnReason>PoorQuality</ReturnReason>
</TransactionLine>
</itemlist>
<transactiontenders>1</transactiontenders>
<transactiontenders>2</transactiontenders>
<transactiontenders>4</transactiontenders>
<transactiontype>1</transactiontype>
<transdate>2017-06-13T09:52:54Z</transdate>
<transtime>09:52</transtime>
</Item>
<Item>
<total>343.59</total>
<terminalid>1</terminalid>
<subtotal>340.29</subtotal>
<storeid>1000</storeid>
<itemlist>
<TransactionLine>
<LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
<Name>Moto G Turbo Edition Black</Name>
<ItemUPC>5479892348535</ItemUPC>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
<SalePrice>330</SalePrice>
<IndividualPrice>330</IndividualPrice>
<CreatedDate>2017-06-13T09:53:00.8548823Z</CreatedDate>
<Status>0</Status>
<ShippingCost>0</ShippingCost>
<TotalTax>3.3</TotalTax>
<AppliedTaxes>
<LineTax>
<TaxId>0</TaxId>
<Amount>0</Amount>
<CreatedDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CreatedDate>
</LineTax>
</AppliedTaxes>
<AppliedDiscounts/>
<ItemCondition>SellableAsNew</ItemCondition>
<ReturnReason>PoorQuality</ReturnReason>
</TransactionLine>
<TransactionLine>
<LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
<Name>This Was A Man</Name>
<ItemUPC>777221028297</ItemUPC>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
<SalePrice>4.99</SalePrice>
<IndividualPrice>4.99</IndividualPrice>
<CreatedDate>2017-06-13T09:53:07.8263895Z</CreatedDate>
<Status>0</Status>
<ShippingCost>0</ShippingCost>
<TotalTax>0</TotalTax>
<AppliedTaxes/>
<AppliedDiscounts/>
<ItemCondition>SellableAsNew</ItemCondition>
<ReturnReason>PoorQuality</ReturnReason>
</TransactionLine>
<TransactionLine>
<LineNumber>3</LineNumber>
<Name>A Prisoner of Birth</Name>
<ItemUPC>4000111222302</ItemUPC>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
<SalePrice>5.3</SalePrice>
<IndividualPrice>5.3</IndividualPrice>
<CreatedDate>2017-06-13T09:53:11.124866Z</CreatedDate>
<Status>0</Status>
<ShippingCost>0</ShippingCost>
<TotalTax>0</TotalTax>
<AppliedTaxes/>
<AppliedDiscounts/>
<ItemCondition>SellableAsNew</ItemCondition>
<ReturnReason>PoorQuality</ReturnReason>
</TransactionLine>
</itemlist>
<transactiontenders>1</transactiontenders>
<transactiontenders>2</transactiontenders>
<transactiontype>1</transactiontype>
<transdate>2017-06-13T09:53:29Z</transdate>
<transtime>09:53</transtime>
</Item>
</ArrayOfItem>'
```

then

```
doc  <-  xmlParse(order.xml.string, asText = TRUE)
y <-
  xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(doc, "//TransactionLine"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
nrow(y) # To get total number of order

numeric.cols <- c("Quantity",
                  "SalePrice",
                  "IndividualPrice",
                  "ShippingCost",
                  "TotalTax")

y[, numeric.cols] <-
  lapply(y[, numeric.cols], as.numeric)

colSums(y[(y$ItemCondition == "SellableAsNew" &
             y$ReturnReason == "PoorQuality"), numeric.cols])

Quantity       SalePrice IndividualPrice    ShippingCost        TotalTax
   4.00          670.29          670.29            0.00            6.60
```

**xmlToList approach:**

I love dataframes as much as anybody, but I don't usually find `xmlToDataFrame` to be a good solution.  I don't think this XML content really has a strictly rectangular shape right now.  For example, even within the TransactionLine paths, it looks like the taxes and rebates paths are nested (not flat).  Even if the current format was suitable for dataframe conversion, it could change in the future, and then you'd need to parse data structures out of dataframe cells.

Maybe consider `xmlToList` instead?  Or even leave the data as XML and apply all of the logic with `XPath` expressions in `xmlApply` functions.

```
order.xml <-
  xmlTreeParse(order.xml.string,
               asText = TRUE,
               useInternalNodes = TRUE)
orders <- xmlRoot(order.xml)
y <- xmlToList(orders)

my.totals <- sapply(y, function(one.item) {
  return(as.numeric(one.item$total))
})

total.total <- sum(my.totals)
print(total.total)

[1] 676.89
```

Comment: Thank you, This is an online order XML for a Day. In a shopping site there would be multiple order placed in a single day. Each Order denoted by tag <Item>. In one order the customer could have bought many items each item denoted by "<itemlist><Transactionline>". Each transaction line will have quantity, status (sale or return), price. If i can convert the list of all transaction lines to a single dataframe, It would be  easier to perform other steps. like which item is most bought, how many sale or return is done. I see in the above code one element is taken out used for summation.

Comment: Thank you, I will try both dataframes and list. As of now, At server side I am converting XML into Json. The whole logic is done on browser using javascript by looping through each order segregating necessary properties. I was worried if response become too big then browser could crash. My colleague asked me to try R programming.